# ¿Por qué cuando quiero pasar un arreglo multidimensional a través del método fetch JS a una api "propia" el arreglo llega null, sin datos?

Tags: javascript

He estado batallando con esto de enviar datos (array multidimensional) a una api para procesarlos y continuar con mi objetivo, pero quedé varado. He leído y visto información en la red y he aplicado distintas soluciones propuestas pero ninguna me funciona.
La cuestión es que en un script lleno un arreglo el cual envío a través de fetch a un api que también estoy creando. Y no sé por qué razón al api llega el arreglo con un contenido null, lo que me impide continuar.
Desde js:

```
var pedidoA=[[],[]];
var pedidoA= new Array(10);//array principal donde se almacena el pedido
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {//se inicaliza con 20 campos para poder llenarlos posteriormente
    pedidoA[i] = new Array(6);
}

function arrayPrincipal(){
        pedidoA[contador]["id"]=id1;
        pedidoA[contador]["referencia"]=referencia1;
        pedidoA[contador]["nombre"]=nombre1;
        pedidoA[contador]["color"]=color1;
        pedidoA[contador]["fabricante"]=fabricante1;
        pedidoA[contador]["caracteristica"]=caracteristica1;
        pedidoA[contador]["precio"]=precio1;
        pedidoA[contador]["cantidad"]=1;
        console.log(pedidoA);
    }
});

const myRequest = 'http://localhost/carritoCompras7/appi/facturacion/api-facturacion2.php?';
                    var myInit = {
                        method:'POST',
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            pedidoA
                          }),
                        headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
                    };

 fetch(myRequest,myInit)//se envia el array del pedido para ser grabado
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then( data =>{ 
                        console.log(data);
                 })
```

Desde mi api:

```
<?php
//include_once 'facturacion2.php';
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
$arrayFactura  = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input',true));
$data=json_encode($arrayFactura);
    echo json_encode(['statuscode' => 200, 'rptaFactura' => $data]);
}
```

Lo que veo en la consola:

```
{statuscode: 200, rptaFactura: '{"pedidoA":[[null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,…null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null]]}'}rptaFactura: "{\"pedidoA\":[[null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null]]}"statuscode: 200[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es que estás declarando cada elemento como un `Array`. Y, aunque un array es un *Objeto* y admite establecer atributos, estos no se añaden a la parte *array*, sino como atributos adicionales del objeto.

Es fácil de ver con un ejemplo:

```
var test = Array( 5 );
test['a'] = 10;
console.log( test );
```

> [ <5 empty items>, a: 10 ]

Como se ve, el atributo `a` se muestra como una entidad **completamente diferenciada** de los elementos del *array*.

Y, si intentamos convertirlo a JSON:

```
var test = Array( 5 );
test['a'] = 10;
console.log( JSON.stringify( test ) );
```

> [null,null,null,null,null]

Un JSON no es capaz de mantener esa diferenciación de elementos. Un *array* es un array; una secuencia de elementos **sin nombre individual**.

La solución es trivial: basta con cambiar

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pedidoA[i] = new Array(6);
}
```

Por

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pedidoA[i] = { };
}
```

Comment: Excelente... muchas gracias. si funciono.

Comment: {statuscode: 200, rptaFactura: '{"pedidoA":[{"totalBruto":95000,"porcentajeDto":0,…":"95000","cantidad":1},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]}'}
rptaFactura
: 
"{\"pedidoA\":[{\"totalBruto\":95000,\"porcentajeDto\":0,\"valorDto\":0,\"descuento\":0,\"total\":95000},{\"id\":\"102035\",\"referencia\":\"Ear-beans\",\"nombre\":\"Ml_Bluetooth\",\"color\":\"Blanco\",\"fabricante\":\"Movisun\",\"caracteristica\":\"Estuche con Display\",\"precio\":\"95000\",\"cantidad\":1},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]}"
statuscode
: 
200

Comment: @Mars, si te funciono la respuesta no olvides marcarla como aceptada, con esto ayudas a otros que tengan tu mismo problema a encontrar solución.